# Why custom view awakeFromNib init set not work in Objc

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib

I have a custom view about alertView.
But when I init my alertView, it seem not set my `awakeFromNib` value of label.
What's wrong about my code?
I can't figure out this issue.
Thanks.

AlertView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface AlertView : UIView
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labTitle;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labMessage;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnCancel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnConfirm;

@end
```

AlertView.m

```
#import "AlertView.h"

@interface AlertView ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *headerView;

@end

@implementation AlertView

-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if(!self){
        return nil;
    }
    self = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([self class])
                                          owner:self
                                        options:nil] firstObject];
    self.frame = frame;
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    // custom label text not show.    
    self.labTitle.text = @"123";
    self.labMessage.text = @"456";
    [self.btnCancel setTitle:@"789"; forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.btnConfirm setTitle:@"111"; forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.btnCancel.layer.cornerRadius = 5.f;
    self.btnConfirm.layer.cornerRadius = 5.f;
    self.headerView.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
}

@end
```

Viewcontroller.m

```
@interface Viewcontroller ()
@property AlertView * alertView;
@end

@implementation Viewcontroller

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[self popupView];
}

- (void)popupView{
    CGRect viewSize = CGRectMake(16, 100, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width - 16 * 2, self.height);
    self.alertView = [[ResultAlertView alloc] initWithFrame:viewSize];
    self.alertView.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    [self SetShadowForView:self.alertView];
    [self.alertView.btnConfirm addTarget:self action:@selector(cancelStartUsingView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.alertView.btnCancel addTarget:self action:@selector(cancelStartUsingView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    
    [self.view addSubview:self.alertView];
}

- (IBAction)cancelStartUsingView:(UIButton *)sender{
    //Btn also not work.
    NSLog(@"123");
}

@end
```

Comment: The nib-loading infrastructure sends an awakeFromNib message to each object recreated from a nib archive, but only after all the objects in the archive have been loaded and initialized. here AlertView is created by initWithFrame:  which is not created from a nib archive

Comment: NSLog to confirm that `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width` is working, IIRC I had issues with that in the past when calling prior to appDidFinishLaunching

Answer (score 0):

**you can use:**

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    self.labTitle.text = @"123";
    self.labMessage.text = @"456";
    [self.btnCancel setTitle:@"789" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.btnConfirm setTitle:@"111"forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.btnCancel.layer.cornerRadius = 5.f;
    self.btnConfirm.layer.cornerRadius = 5.f;
    self.headerView.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
}
```

**and call**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           [self popupView];
      });
}
```